# Android Studio is asking Authentication Code for GitHub for every Pull Request

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I have an Android project on GitHub, and can use Git for that in Android Studio. Pulling, pushing, creating new branches and everything works fine so far.

I can create Pull Requests in Android Studio with

```
VCS > Git > Create Pull Request
```

But for creating a PR, Android Studio asks me for my authentication code, because I have 2-factor authentication enables. This is sent to my by text message and works fine. However, it's a bit annoying that I have to do this for every PR. Is there a way to make Android Studio remember, that I'm authenticated?

Comment: Did you try to use a Personal Access Token ? https://github.com/settings/tokens

Comment: And if yes, are you sure you enabled this token to do Pull Requests in the token's scope ?

Comment: How can I enable it to do pull requests? I don't see this option there.

Comment: I just checked it for my token... and I don't see it anywhere either. Plus, https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes doesn't even talk about Pull Requests. So I'll assume it's simply not possible for now. :/